# Is it possible to access the fields of a 'DNSError' struct embedded within an 'OpError' struct from the Go 'net' package?

Tags: go

I am starting an SSH client connection in Go and I am trying to access detailed error data when an error is returned.

I am currently using this code:

```
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "unknownserver:22", config)
if err != nil {
    if oerr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
        a := oerr.Err
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
    }
    log.Fatal("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
}
```

which returns these two lines of error data:

```
&net.DNSError{Err:"no such host", Name:"unknownserver", Server:"", IsTimeout:false, IsTemporary:false}
2016/06/23 11:59:00 Failed to dial: dial tcp: lookup unknownserver: no such host
```

I am trying to print the contents of the `Name` field inside [net.DNSError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DNSError) by using this:

```
fmt.Println(a.Name)
```

however when attempting to compile the code I get this error:

```
a.Name undefined (type error has no field or method Name)
```

If `oerr` is a struct of type [net.OpError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#OpError) and `oerr.Err` is a struct of type **net.DNSError** and has fields `{Err:"no such host", Name:"unknownserver", Server:"", IsTimeout:false, IsTemporary:false}`, is it possible to access the struct's fields? Or am I misunderstanding a key concept here?

Thanks,

-Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a second type assertion conditional:

```
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "unknownserver:22", config)
if err != nil {
    if oerr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
        a := oerr.Err
        if d, ok := a.(*net.DNSError); ok {
            fmt.Println(d.Name)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
    }
    log.Fatal("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
}
```

The first type-assertion sets `oerr` as a `*net.OpError`, but the `Err` field of that structure is of type `error`, which is a built-in interface type (so it has no fields).  To access the fields of that error, you first have to assert that it's a structure (specifically, the `*net.DNSError` structure you want), then you can access the (exported) fields of that structure.

Comment: Thanks for that Kaedys! Your explanation about the second type assertion has clarified different pieces of information in the docs and source that I had not yet successfully pieced together regarding the `error` interface. But now this aspect has become clearer and I have been able to extract the desired data thanks to your example.